# Warning : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php

I know this same warning has been asked many times here.
But in all the queries I saw some mistake in the program because of which the user was not able to access the database.

But in my case I am accessing directly using the user which has access rights to the database, but even then this warning is coming

`php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known`

```
<?php

$conn_error = 'Could not connect.';
$mysql_host  = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

$mysql_db = 'a_database';

if(!mysqli_connect('mysql_host','mysql_user','mysql_pass','mysql_db')){
die($conn_error);
}
else{
  echo 'connected';
}
```

It is giving the error message of not connected.

Although the users have the privilege to access the database.
[image]

Comment: you really should learn to read the error message. "no such host" means that your code can't even **TRY** to log in to mysql, since it can't even reach the db server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to put the `$` in (as variables)

```
if(!mysqli_connect('mysql_host','mysql_user','mysql_pass','mysql_db'))
```

those are being treated as strings.

- You're trying to connect to a host called "mysql_host", which is why it's not finding the intended "localhost" server address, as per `$mysql_host  = 'localhost';`.

Therefore, replace that with; while removing the quotes.

*Sidenote:* If you intend on putting the `$` inside single quotes, it won't work. Variables do not get parsed in single quotes, but in double quotes, however they're not required here. Consult "references" below.

```
if(!mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db))
```

and this `die($conn_error);` (Could not connect.) doesn't help you.

This does:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Reference(s):

- https://php.net/language.types.string
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php